# Nuxt page doesn't render array from Pinia store

Tags: nuxtjs3, pinia, nuxt3

I have Nuxt page for products list with `fetchProducts()` method from pinia store.

The problem is that product list NOT rendered on page 1st visit.

```
<script setup>
import { storeToRefs}   from "pinia";
import { useShopStore } from '@/stores/shop'

const shop = useShopStore();
shop.fetchProducts();
const {products} = storeToRefs(shop)
const hasProducts = computed(() => products.value.length > 0);

</script>

<template>
    <NuxtLayout>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Products</h2>
            <div class="container" v-if="hasProducts">
                  <div class="row row-cols-1 gap-3">
                    <ProductCard :product="product" v-for="product in products" :key="product.id"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div v-else>
                <h3>Products NOT loaded</h3><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

As you can see on following snapshot products are loaded and available in pinia store, but array `products` on page is empty.

[image]

If I go back to home and return to product page products are rendered without any problem or warnings in console.

Any suggestion what I can do to fix or even investigate the issue?

PS. Store code if it's matter here

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

import Product  from "@/models/Product";

export const useShopStore = defineStore('shop', {
    state: () => ({
        //products: <Product[]>[]
        products: [] as Product[]
    }),
    actions: {
        fetchProducts: async function () {
            try {
                const {data} = await useFetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
                //TODO - fix this  typescript error `TS2352: Conversion of type 'Ref<unknown>' to type 'Product[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other.`
                // @ts-ignore
                this.products = data as Product[];
            } catch (error) {
                return error
            }
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: does it work if you fetch in `script setup` (not in store)?

Comment: @Orbis I do call shop.fetchProducts(); from `script setup` which is working. I mean store.products are loaded (please see snapshot)

Comment: FYI: typescript error `TS2352` by using `await useFetch<Product[]>(...)`

Comment: @Orbis. Thank you for note that. Can you tell me more about TS2352? Is it a problem with `await`?

Comment: TL;DR: typecasting should only be used if you can't solve it with generics. In this case TS knows, that `Ref<unknown>` does not overlap with `Product[]`. The reason: `data` seems to be an `ref` and `Product` is not. `this.products = data as Ref<Product[]>` might work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how valid it is, but assign `this.products = data.value as Product[];` instead of `this.products = data as Product[];` seems to fix the issue.

```
fetchProducts: async function () {
  try {
    
    // TODO - fix this  typescript error `TS2352: Conversion of type 'Ref<unknown>' to type 'Product[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other.`  // @ts-expect-error

        // NOTE: OPTION 1, with useFetch() -> require import
        const { data } = await useFetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
        this.products = (await data.value) as Product[]

        // NOTE: OPTION 2, with fetch()
        // const response = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
        // this.products = (await response.json()) as Product[]
  } catch (error) {
    return error
  }
}
```

Please let me know if it's a good solution or not. I'm still learning Vue 3 and Nuxt 3 and not sure that using `useFetch` inside pinia store is a good idea.

Comment: data is a `Ref`. Not just the `response.data`.

Comment: Although it is a valid solution, according to the nuxt doc: "useFetch is a composable meant to be called directly in a setup function, plugin, or route middleware..."(https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch ); I think that useFetch would be better used in a somePage.vue, so I would take advantage of values returned {pending,...} which applies in your specific case using hasProducts, which you will get a better idea with (https://nuxt.com /docs/getting-started/data-fetching#lazy)

Comment: If you want to use the flux pattern (base of Vuex, predecessor of Pinia) and it is possible that those who come from Vuex want to make their requests to the API in Store, it would be better to use fetch / axios so that they get along better take advantage of the resources that you offers each option, e.g. have a custom handleRequests. While UseFetch can be used in Store (Pinia), you might encounter some bugs, as you can check in codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/old-sea-lc2mq5?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.vue%3A1%2C1); where is also the demo to specifically solve the current question.

Comment: @GustavoIAS Thanks. I came from Vuex/axios where I haven't had such problems. Now I'm learning Nuxt with Pinia and having lot of surprises. )))